# Best macOS for 13 inch MacBook Pro mid 2012

Tags: macbook-pro

What is the best macOS for MacBook Pro 13 inch mid 2012. macOS Catalina is running very slow.

Comment: Do you have a internal HDD or SSD?

Comment: Here”s a thought - it was designed for the one it shipped with...

Answer (score 1):

Your question is based on the premise that it is the OS that is causing the slowness. That needs testing, first of all.
If Apple says an OS will run on that Mac, that means it should run fine. (Indeed, one of the reasons they cut off older Macs is because the new OS doesn't run ***well***.)

If you still have the original hard drive, then that's the likeliest cause of slowness, and it should be replaced by an SSD -- to improve reliability, if nothing else. (If you've already done that, then make sure the SSD has at least 20% free space.)

Not enough RAM could also be a factor (combined with swapping onto slow storage media). If you haven't already maxed it to 16 GB, do so.

Or it could be that the slowness is caused by software: things you've installed, possibly for a previous OS, that now don't play well on Catalina. Test booting into Safe Boot Mode (hold down <kbd>shift</kbd> at boot), or running in a brand new user account that doesn't have all the Login Items and Launch Agents of your existing account.

The 'best' OS is the one that lets you run the apps that you need, while supporting your hardware. Your MBP won't run Big Sur, so you're already falling into 'legacy' territory. As time marches on, you'll increasingly have to stay on older versions of apps and not keep up with the newest and shiniest.

Comment: Thank you for detailed reply.. I appreciate your analasis... the actual problem what I sort out is .. RAM .. it is 4 Gb ram..   I have to replace it or else upgrade the max into latest models..thank you once again..

Comment: 16 GB for your Mac should be cheap, and it's easy to fit.

Comment: If it so... but I can’t upgrade a later versions of macOS..